# How to send and receive data between flask framework web server and android app

Tags: android, python, flask

I am unable to communicate to receive and send reply between the web server(which uses flask framework) and my android app whose code is as shown below. 
If possible can you please post a sample server end code which might solve my problem.

```
package com.project.nsj;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String userName, passkey;
    EditText username, password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //checkLogin login = new checkLogin();
                //login.execute();
                Intent funcs = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Functions.class);
                startActivity(funcs);
            }
        });

    }

    public class checkLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

            userName = username.getText().toString();
            passkey = password.getText().toString();

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://rpihomeautomation.no-ip.biz");

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", userName));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passkey", passkey));

            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            HttpResponse response;
            int status = 0;
            try {
                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return status;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result == 200) {
                Intent funcs = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Functions.class);
                startActivity(funcs);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid password/username",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How is your Flask application deployed? What kind of errors are you getting when you try to use this code?

Comment: The fact is that I am new to python and totally clueless when it comes to sending and receiving data between the app and the server. It will be really helpful if you could send a sample code that can be implemented on the server end to receive a string and send a reply.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest case for handling a HTTP POST request is:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/data", method=("POST",))
def handle_data():
    return "Hello World - you sent me " + str(request.values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```